# Cannot update extensions in the Web Setup Wizard

Tags: magento2, extensions, dependency, web-setup-wizard, readiness-check

I am currently trying to update two MSP exensions in my version of Magento 2.3.2. But whenever I run the readiness check I get the following error:

> Check Component Dependency We found conflicting component
>   dependencies. Hide detail
>
> Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.2].
>   - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 requires msp/twofactorauth 3.1.1 -> satisfiable by msp/twofactorauth[3.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

[image]

I've tried the solutions in the help documents but none of them seem to work.

The composer file seems to have the correct requirements:

> ```
> "require": {
>     "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",
>     "composer/composer": "@alpha",
>     "mageplaza/module-gdpr": "^1.2",
>     "msp/twofactorauth": "3.1.1",
>     "msp/recaptcha": "2.1.2",
>     "xtento/customtrackers": "2.1.7",
>     "zendframework/zend-mime": "^2.7",
>     "geoip2/geoip2": "^2.9",
>     "livechat/module-magento-livechat": "2.3.0"
> },
> "require-dev": {
>     "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
>     "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
>     "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
>     "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~1.0.0",
>     "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.14",
>     "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
>     "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
>     "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
>     "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
>     "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
> },
> ```

I've run the usual commands as follows but these have not resolved the issue:

```
composer update
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've come up with a basic solution. Not ideal but here goes:

Essentially I removed `twofactorauth` and `recaptcha` from composer.json then updated the magento 2 system to the next version (2.3.4). Once this was complete I used:

```
composer require
```

To put the latest versions of the extensions back. The site now seems to be working  properly.